# google.visualization.ChartWrapper Group Columns View

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am new using Google visualisation API plus I am not very familiar with JavaScript.

What I want my output to do is to group by labels from column 2. Notice that New York is repeated on the chart. I would just want the chart to group column 2 by label and sum the numeric values in column 3. Does anybody know how?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Prepare the data
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Region/State', 'City', 'Population'],
          ['USA', 'California', 'San Francisco', 776733],
          ['USA', 'California', 'Los Angeles', 3694820],
          ['USA', 'California', 'Mountain View', 70708],
          ['USA', 'New York', 'New York', 8175173],
          ['USA', 'New York', 'New York', 8175173],
          ['USA', 'New York', 'Albany', 857592],
          ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Paris', 2193031],
          ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Orly', 21372],
          ['France', 'Provence', 'Marseille', 852395],
          ['France', 'Provence', 'Nice', 348556]
        ]);

        // Define category pickers for 'Country', 'Region/State' and 'City'
        var countryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'control1',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Country',
            'ui': {
              'labelStacking': 'vertical',
              'allowTyping': false,
              'allowMultiple': false
            }
          }
        });

        var regionPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'control2',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Region/State',
            'ui': {
              'labelStacking': 'vertical',
              'allowTyping': false,
              'allowMultiple': false
            }
          }
        });

        var cityPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'control3',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'City',
            'ui': {
              'labelStacking': 'vertical',
              'allowTyping': false,
              'allowMultiple': false
            }
          }
        });

        // Define a bar chart to show 'Population' data
        var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'BarChart',
          'containerId': 'chart1',
          'options': {
            'width': 400,
            'height': 300,
            'chartArea': {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}
          },
          // Configure the barchart to use columns 2 (City) and 3 (Population)
          'view': {'columns': [2, 3]}
        });

        // Create the dashboard.
        new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
          // Configure the controls so that:
          // - the 'Country' selection drives the 'Region' one,
          // - the 'Region' selection drives the 'City' one,
          // - and finally the 'City' output drives the chart
          bind(countryPicker, regionPicker).
          bind(regionPicker, cityPicker).
          bind(cityPicker, barChart).
          // Draw the dashboard
          draw(data);
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="dashboard">
      <table>
        <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
          <td style='width: 300px; font-size: 0.9em;'>
            <div id="control1"></div>
            <div id="control2"></div>
            <div id="control3"></div>
          </td>
          <td style='width: 600px'>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart1"></div>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart2"></div>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart3"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work, you need an intermediary visualization to act as a proxy in the Dashboard (I typically use a Table for this).  The Dashboard binds the proxy to your controls (instead of binding your chart to the controls).  In a "ready" event handler for the proxy, you need to aggregate the proxy's data and use the aggregated data to draw your chart.  Here's an example:

```
function drawVisualization() {
    // Prepare the data
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Region/State', 'City', 'Population'],
        ['USA', 'California', 'San Francisco', 776733],
        ['USA', 'California', 'Los Angeles', 3694820],
        ['USA', 'California', 'Mountain View', 70708],
        ['USA', 'New York', 'New York', 8175173],
        ['USA', 'New York', 'New York', 8175173],
        ['USA', 'New York', 'Albany', 857592],
        ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Paris', 2193031],
        ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Orly', 21372],
        ['France', 'Provence', 'Marseille', 852395],
        ['France', 'Provence', 'Nice', 348556]
    ]);

    // Define category pickers for 'Country', 'Region/State' and 'City'
    var countryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'control1',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Country',
            'ui': {
                'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'allowTyping': false,
                'allowMultiple': false
            }
        }
    });

    var regionPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'control2',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Region/State',
            'ui': {
                'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'allowTyping': false,
                'allowMultiple': false
            }
        }
    });

    var cityPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'control3',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'City',
            'ui': {
                'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'allowTyping': false,
                'allowMultiple': false
            }
        }
    });

    // Define a bar chart to show 'Population' data
    var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'BarChart',
        'containerId': 'chart1',
        'options': {
            'width': 400,
            'height': 300,
            'chartArea': {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}
        },
        // Configure the barchart to use columns 2 (City) and 3 (Population)
        'view': {'columns': [2, 3]}
    });

    var proxyTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'Table',
        containerId: 'proxyTable',
        options: {
            // minimize the footprint of the table in HTML
            page: 'enable',
            pageSize: 1
        },
        view: {
            columns: [0]
        }
    });

    // create a "ready" event handler for proxyTable the handles data aggregation and drawing barChart
    google.visualization.events.addListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function () {
        var dt = proxyTable.getDataTable();
        var groupedData = google.visualization.data.group(dt, [0, 1, 2], [{
            column: 3,
            type: 'number',
            label: dt.getColumnLabel(3),
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
        }]);
        // after grouping, the data will be sorted by column 0, then 1, then 2
        // if you want a different order, you have to re-sort
        barChart.setDataTable(groupedData);
        barChart.draw();
    });

    // Create the dashboard.
    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
    // Configure the controls so that:
    // - the 'Country' selection drives the 'Region' one,
    // - the 'Region' selection drives the 'City' one,
    // - and finally the 'City' output drives proxyTable
    bind(countryPicker, regionPicker).
    bind(regionPicker, cityPicker).
    bind(cityPicker, proxyTable).
    // Draw the dashboard
    draw(data);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart', 'controls', 'table'], callback: drawVisualization});
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/MebSS/