# Google Bar Chart with Percentage of Total and with Category Filters

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I am fairly new to Google Charts and was trying to create a bar chart with % of total, along with the ability to filter the data by using Google Dashboard Controls...  I followed this (thanks to @asgallant for this!) [google.visualization.ChartWrapper Group Columns View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815448/google-visualization-chartwrapper-group-columns-view) and was able to get a bar chart which picks up data from a google sheet, and draws the chart with counts and also have the ability to filter the data using Google Category filters.

However, this is where I am stuck - when I try to add another columns (dataview) for calculating the total (so that I can draw the chart using the percentage and also show the percentage in the bar labels) - my chart is still drawing using the counts.. Can anyone please let me know what am I going wrong here:

```
function drawVisualization() {

    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LBoS8Q7qdpWVjks3FytQAefThzY3VbAHllf04nE6qO8/edit?gid=1629614877&range=A:D');
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);

    function handleQueryResponse(response) {
     if (response.isError()) {return; }
    var data = response.getDataTable();


        // Define category pickers for All Filters
        var CardTier = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
            'containerId': 'control1',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnLabel': 'CardTier Filter',
                'ui': {
                    'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                    'allowTyping': false,
                    'allowMultiple': false
                }
            }
        });

        var Campaign = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
            'containerId': 'control2',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnLabel': 'Campaign Filter',
                'ui': {
                    'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                    'allowTyping': false,
                    'allowMultiple': false
                }
            }
        });


        // Define a bar chart to show 'Population' data
        var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'BarChart',
            'containerId': 'chart1',
            'options': {
                'width': 400,
                'height': 300,
                'chartArea': {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}
            },
            // Configure the barchart to use columns 0 (Card Tier) and 1 (Campaign Filter) (Basically the filters)
            'view': {'columns': [0, 1]}
        });

        var proxyTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'Table',
            containerId: 'proxyTable',
            options: {
                // minimize the footprint of the table in HTML
                page: 'enable',
                pageSize: 1
            },
            view: {
                columns: [0]
            }
        });



        // create a "ready" event handler for proxyTable the handles data aggregation and drawing barChart
        // Add The question's column index here. We want to draw Status so we Group 2 with dt and also its count...
        google.visualization.events.addListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function () {
            var dt = proxyTable.getDataTable();
            var groupedData = google.visualization.data.group(dt, [2], [{
                column: 3,
                type: 'number',
                label: dt.getColumnLabel(2),
                aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
            }]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(groupedData);
      view.setColumns([0, 1, {
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          var amount =  formatShort.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1));
          var percent = formatPercent.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1) / groupedData.getValue(0, 1));
          return amount + ' (' + percent + ')';
        },
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'
      }]);


            // after grouping, the data will be sorted by column 0, then 1, then 2
            // if you want a different order, you have to re-sort
            barChart.setDataTable(view);
            barChart.draw();

    });



        // Create the dashboard.
        new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
        // Configure the controls :
        bind(CardTier, Campaign).
        bind(Campaign, proxyTable).
        // Draw the dashboard
        draw(data);
    }
    }

    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart', 'controls', 'table'], callback: drawVisualization});




    </script>
    </head>


      <body>

    <div id="dashboard">
        <table>
            <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
                <td style='width: 300px; font-size: 0.9em;'>
                    <div id="control1"></div>
                    <div id="control2"></div>
                </td>
                <td style='width: 600px'>
                    <div style="float: left;" id="chart1"></div>
                    <div style="float: left;" id="chart2"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="proxyTable" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>

    </body>  
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for starters, recommend using the newer library `loader.js`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

instead of `jsapi`, according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see following working snippet...

---

next, didn't see the definitions for the number formatters
`formatShort` and `formatPercent`
need to add those

---

`groupedData` will give you the total for each status
to get the the total for all the rows,
need to use the `modifier` function
this will change the value to `'Total'` for the first column of all rows
allowing the `group` method to aggregate all rows

```
  var totalData = google.visualization.data.group(
    dataTable,
    [{column: 0, type: 'string', modifier: function () {return 'Total';}}],
    [{
      column: 3,
      type: 'number',
      label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(2),
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
    }]
  );
```

---

finally, remove the `view` option from `barChart`
since we're providing the `view` we want drawn

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls', 'table']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LBoS8Q7qdpWVjks3FytQAefThzY3VbAHllf04nE6qO8/edit?gid=1629614877&range=A:D');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {return; }
    var data = response.getDataTable();

    // Define category pickers for All Filters
    var CardTier = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'control1',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'CardTier Filter',
        'ui': {
          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false
        }
      }
    });

    var Campaign = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'control2',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Campaign Filter',
        'ui': {
          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false
        }
      }
    });

    // Define a bar chart to show 'Population' data
    var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'BarChart',
      'containerId': 'chart1',
      'options': {
        'width': 400,
        'height': 300,
        'chartArea': {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}
      }
    });

    var proxyTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      containerId: 'proxyTable',
      options: {
        // minimize the footprint of the table in HTML
        page: 'enable',
        pageSize: 1
      },
      view: {
        columns: [0]
      }
    });

    // create a "ready" event handler for proxyTable the handles data aggregation and drawing barChart
    // Add The question's column index here. We want to draw Status so we Group 2 with dt and also its count...
    google.visualization.events.addListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function () {
      var formatShort = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        pattern: 'short'
      });
      var formatPercent = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        pattern: '0.0%'
      });
      var dataTable = proxyTable.getDataTable();

      // group by status
      var groupedData = google.visualization.data.group(
        dataTable,
        [2],
        [{
          column: 3,
          type: 'number',
          label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(2),
          aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
        }]
      );

      // status total
      var totalData = google.visualization.data.group(
        dataTable,
        [{column: 0, type: 'string', modifier: function () {return 'Total';}}],
        [{
          column: 3,
          type: 'number',
          label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(2),
          aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
        }]
      );

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(groupedData);
      view.setColumns([0, 1, {
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          var amount =  dt.getValue(row, 1);
          var total = totalData.getValue(0, 1);
          var percent = 0;
          if (total > 0) {
            percent = amount / total;
          }
          return formatShort.formatValue(amount) + ' (' + formatPercent.formatValue(percent) + ')';
        },
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'
      }]);

      // after grouping, the data will be sorted by column 0, then 1, then 2
      // if you want a different order, you have to re-sort
      barChart.setDataTable(view);
      barChart.draw();
    });

    // Create the dashboard.
    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
    // Configure the controls :
    bind(CardTier, Campaign).
    bind(Campaign, proxyTable).
    // Draw the dashboard
    draw(data);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="control1"></div>
<div id="control2"></div>
<div id="chart1"></div>
<div id="proxyTable"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

to draw the percentages instead of counts,
just need to add another calculated column to the `view`

as for showing zero values,
use the original data table to get a distinct list of status values
check if the status exists in `groupedData`
if not, add a row for the status

```
  // add back missing status
  var statusValues = data.getDistinctValues(2);
  statusValues.forEach(function (status) {
    var statusRow = groupedData.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      value: status
    }]);
    if (statusRow.length === 0) {
      groupedData.addRow([
        status,
        0
      ]);
    }
  });
  groupedData.sort([{column: 0}]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls', 'table']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LBoS8Q7qdpWVjks3FytQAefThzY3VbAHllf04nE6qO8/edit?gid=1629614877&range=A:D');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {return; }
    var data = response.getDataTable();

    // Define category pickers for All Filters
    var CardTier = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'control1',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'CardTier Filter',
        'ui': {
          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false
        }
      }
    });

    var Campaign = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'control2',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Campaign Filter',
        'ui': {
          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false
        }
      }
    });

    // Define a bar chart to show 'Population' data
    var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'BarChart',
      'containerId': 'chart1',
      'options': {
        'width': 400,
        'height': 300,
        'chartArea': {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}
      }
    });

    var proxyTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      containerId: 'proxyTable',
      options: {
        // minimize the footprint of the table in HTML
        page: 'enable',
        pageSize: 1
      },
      view: {
        columns: [0]
      }
    });

    // create a "ready" event handler for proxyTable the handles data aggregation and drawing barChart
    // Add The question's column index here. We want to draw Status so we Group 2 with dt and also its count...
    google.visualization.events.addListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function () {
      var formatShort = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        pattern: 'short'
      });
      var formatPercent = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        pattern: '0.0%'
      });
      var dataTable = proxyTable.getDataTable();

      // group by status
      var groupedData = google.visualization.data.group(
        dataTable,
        [2],
        [{
          column: 3,
          type: 'number',
          label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(2),
          aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
        }]
      );

      // add back missing status
      var statusValues = data.getDistinctValues(2);
      statusValues.forEach(function (status) {
        var statusRow = groupedData.getFilteredRows([{
          column: 0,
          value: status
        }]);
        if (statusRow.length === 0) {
          groupedData.addRow([
            status,
            0
          ]);
        }
      });
      groupedData.sort([{column: 0}]);

      // status total
      var totalData = google.visualization.data.group(
        dataTable,
        [{column: 0, type: 'string', modifier: function () {return 'Total';}}],
        [{
          column: 3,
          type: 'number',
          label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(2),
          aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
        }]
      );

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(groupedData);
      view.setColumns([0, {
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          var amount =  dt.getValue(row, 1);
          var total = totalData.getValue(0, 1);
          var percent = 0;
          if (total > 0) {
            percent = amount / total;
          }
          return {
            v: percent,
            f: formatPercent.formatValue(percent)
          };
        },
        type: 'number',
        label: 'Percent'
      }, {
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          var amount =  dt.getValue(row, 1);
          var total = totalData.getValue(0, 1);
          var percent = 0;
          if (total > 0) {
            percent = amount / total;
          }
          return formatPercent.formatValue(percent) + ' (' + formatShort.formatValue(amount) + ')';
        },
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'
      }]);

      // after grouping, the data will be sorted by column 0, then 1, then 2
      // if you want a different order, you have to re-sort
      barChart.setDataTable(view);
      barChart.draw();
    });

    // Create the dashboard.
    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
    // Configure the controls :
    bind(CardTier, Campaign).
    bind(Campaign, proxyTable).
    // Draw the dashboard
    draw(data);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="control1"></div>
<div id="control2"></div>
<div id="chart1"></div>
<div id="proxyTable"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

to find the total of a multiple choice question,
create a view with a calculated column
the new column should test that all question columns are not blank
then total the view on the calculated column

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls', 'table']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19VWNZkHG5GEuYCibDmtOlKblKiOWcx94Wi9jyuhvEUo/edit#gid=0');
  query.setQuery('select A,B,C,D,E,F,G');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {return;}
    var data = response.getDataTable();

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        var answered = 0;
        var q1_1 = dt.getValue(row, 3) || '';
        var q1_2 = dt.getValue(row, 4) || '';
        var q1_3 = dt.getValue(row, 5) || '';
        var q1_4 = dt.getValue(row, 6) || '';
        if ((q1_1 !== '') || (q1_2 !== '') || (q1_3 !== '') || (q1_4 !== '')) {
          answered = 1;
        }
        return answered;
      },
      label: 'Answered',
      type: 'number'
    }]);

    var totalAnswered = google.visualization.data.group(
      view,
      [{column: 0, type: 'string', modifier: function () {return 'Total';}}],
      [{
        column: view.getNumberOfColumns() - 1,
        type: 'number',
        label: view.getColumnLabel(view.getNumberOfColumns() - 1),
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
      }]
    );

    var proxyTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      containerId: 'proxyTable',
      dataTable: view
    });
    proxyTable.draw();

    document.getElementById('proxyTableTotal').innerHTML = 'Total Answered = ' + totalAnswered.getValue(0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="proxyTable"></div>
<div id="proxyTableTotal"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this!! You really are a hero! I was getting so confused with this but your answer has helped clarify things a lot!!! Just one more help - Can you also let me know how to draw the chart using the percentage (the total variable) instead of the counts? And I also noticed that if you select filters Card 4 and Campaign 2 - there are no resolved cases so the chart only draws two bars and does not draw a "zero" value bar for the Resolved category - is there any way to show this even if its zero?

Comment: Hi @WhiteHat - I had a followup question.Using the method you provided, the solution works perfectly but I am getting stuck in analyzing the for Multiple Choice Questions - basically these are checkbox questions where you can select more than one answer, and so the data is present in multiple cols. I have created some sample data on this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19VWNZkHG5GEuYCibDmtOlKblKiOWcx94Wi9jyuhvEUo/edit. How would the totalling be done for these set of columns (the total for this question should be 8) - any help you can do here?

Comment: Wow that is just AMAZING!!! I have to create a chart similar to earlier charts using this total but let me try using this 'answered' column in the charts. I cannot express how thankful I am to you, you really are an expert on Google Visualization!!!

Comment: I spoke too soon I think, I tried creating a new view (view2) and tried to chart based on this new view2 (which has the columns 3,4,5,6 and the TotalAnswered) but I am getting errors. SO is not letting me paste my code here so have pasted my code in Sheet 2 of the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19VWNZkHG5GEuYCibDmtOlKblKiOWcx94Wi9jyuhvEUo/edit#gid=0 . Basically I want to create a bar chart with the percentage of yes's for each column in Q1 using the total (so first bar would have 50%, i.e. 4/8. second bar should be 37.5, i.e. 3/8 and so on... please could you help me again.